# Help with first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find particular solution of equation $$x'=x^2-tx-t$$ knowing that its general solution is in form $x(t)=ct+d$

First off I evaluated $c$ and $d$ to be $1$ and $1$ by substituting given solution to the equation.

But I dont know what to do from here on. I'd consider this a Riccati's equation, but I dont have one of the particular solutions.

Also this cannot be Bernoulli's equation because of the single $t$.

Comment: Once you know $c$ and $d$ what else you need?

Answer (score 0):

Hint : In the equation, replace $x$ by $ct+d$ and replace $x'$ by $c$. Then simplify and found the values of $c$ and $d$ so that the equation be valid any $x$

The equation is a Riccati ODE. The particular solution already found permits to transform it into a Bernoulli equation. Let $x(t)=y(t)+(t+1)$

Comment: Wont that be only the particular solution, and not the general one?

Comment: Yes, but it permits to transform the Riccati ODE to a Bernoulli ODE that we know how to solve.

Comment: OK so I get $u'= 2 + t +\frac 1 u$ and that doesnt look like Bernoulli's equation to me. Is that what I should have gotten after substituting?